# Routes ignoring path to controller

Tags: yii, yii2

```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName'  => false,
            'rules'           => [
                [
                    'class'  => 'yii\web\GroupUrlRule',
                    'prefix' => 'user',
                    'rules'  => [
                        # Url Path           # Path to controller
                        'registration/'      => 'FAKE DATA',
                        'password-recovery/',
                    ],
                ]

            ],
```

It seems my routes ‘registration/' and 'password-recovery/' are not determined by path to controller but only by the url path. As you can see on the first one I put 'FAKE DATA' and on the second one I didn't put anything at all.
I don't even understand how the routes can be working.
How can I specify a path to controller route in this case ?

EDIT: in fact, the entire 'rules' section is ignored. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afaik, the `GroupUrlRule` is only used to simplify the rules sharing the same prefix in their patterns and routes. If you have these rules,

```
[
    'class'  => 'yii\web\GroupUrlRule',
    'prefix' => 'user',
    'rules'  => [
        # Url Path           # Path to controller
        'registration/'      => 'fake', //there should be actionFake on UserController 
        'password-recovery/' => '',
    ],
]
```

URL `user/registration` will hit the `actionFake` on `UserController`. Showing the content of your UserController could be useful.